# Assign ID to Main Menu

Tags: routes

I am working on Drupal 7 project (omega 4 subtheme) with panels and views. I need to assign ID an ID (id="nav") to a DIV that wraps main menu UL. It is a child of div.l-region--navigation. It's the second row of the example bellow.

```
<div class="l-region l-region--navigation">
<div class="panel-pane pane-block pane-system-main-menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Anyone knows how to do this? Is there a specific drupal way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

```
function mytheme_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
$site_frontpage = variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node');
  $html = "<nav id='main-nav' class='animate'>\n";
  foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
      if($link['href'] == '<front>') {
        $html .= "<a class='1' href='" .$site_frontpage ."'>" .$link['title'] ."</a>";
      }
      else {
        $html .= "<a class='2' href='" .$link['href'] ."'>" .$link['title'] ."</a>";
      }
  }
  $html .= "</nav>\n";

  return $html;
}
```

The code can be used in template.php to override the output of the . However, the only variable it seems to accept is $tree, which prints out all the contents of a  and so is not very helpful.

Comment: I agree - not very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve that using the [Menu attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module

> This simple module allows you to specify some additional attributes for menu items such as id, name, class, style, and rel.

Comment: This sounds pretty much what I need. BTW, do you know can I target the wrapping DIV or only Menu Items such as <li>?

Comment: @ Krishna Mohan, I checked the module and it allows additional attributes only on link items (a:). That's nice but not what I need.